# How to minimize the performance hit of deleting lots of rows from a highly active table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has tens of thousands of new rows added a hour.

Based on certain events I set a given row a state of complete by setting it's `status` field to 1, update it's status_timesamp and then when querying the table with selects, I ignore all rows with field of 1.

But this leads to a huge amount of rows that I no longer need all with a field of 1. I also may need the fields at a later point in the future for logging purposes, but for the everyday purpose of my application such rows aren't needed.

I could delete the row instead of updating the field to 1 but I figure a delete is more costly than an update and many inserts are happening per second.

Ultimately I would like a way to move all the rows with status 1 into some kind of log table, without impacting on the current table which has many inserts and updates happening per second.

Comment: *Not* deleting the items is even more costly, in terms of insert and query performance. There are 86,400 seconds in a day, so tens of thousands per day is actually less than 0.116 per second per ten thousand, which is nothing, certainly nowhere near many per second.

Comment: I meant hour not day, dont know if that matters. I'm also more interested if there is a more efficient way than deleting a field as the status changes and writing it to the log. Just imagine the number of inserts per second is many for the purposes of the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer.  Indeed, updates (on a non-indexed field) should be faster than deletes.  In a simple environment, you would do the delete, along with a trigger that logged the information that you wanted.

I find it hard to believe that there is no downtime for the database.  Can't you do the deletes at 2:00 a.m. once per week on Sunday, in some time zone?

Normally if this isn't the case, then you have high-availability requirements.  And, in such a circumstance, you would have a replicated database.  Most times, inserts, updates, and queries would go to both databases.  During database maintenance periods, only one might be up while the other "does maintenance".  Then that database catches up with the transactions, takes over the user load, and the other database "does maintenance".  In your case "does maintenance" means doing the delete and logging.

If you have a high availability requirement and you are not using replication of some sort, your system has bigger vulnerabilities than simply accumulating to-be-deleted data.